# golang protobuf can not unmarshal in a generic type

Tags: go, generics, protobuf-go, go-generate

```golang
type Msg[T any] interface {
    *T
    proto.Message
}

func Handle[T any, U Msg[T]](cb func(req U) (proto.Message, error)) {
    msg := new(T)
    if err := proto.Unmarshal([]byte{}, msg); err != nil {
    }
    _, _ = cb(msg)
}

func main() {
    Handle(donSomething)
}

func doSomething(req *pb.Hello) (proto.Message, error) {
    _ = proto.Unmarshal([]byte{}, req)
    return nil, nil
}
```

why proto.Unmarshal Cannot use 'msg' (type *T) as the type Message in Handle generic funcion.

how can i use `new(T)` in a generic funcion with protobuf

Answer (score 3):

In your program `T` is constrained by `any`, so the pointer type `*T` bears no relation to the protobuffer type anymore. It's just a pointer to an unspecified type.

Instead use:

```
msg := U(new(T))
```

This way you have a non-nil pointer to whatever `T` is inferred to — here it will be `pb.Hello`, `new(T)` creates a pointer to a `pb.Hello` zero value, and the conversion `U()` tells the compiler that `*T` really satisfies the `proto.Message` interface.

Comment: yeh, and i find `proto.Unmarshal([]byte{}, (any)(msg)(proto.Message))` can work. thank you